# Make ul lists alongside each other

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make two lists with a header of each one.

I need to make these two lists beside each other with a header above each one, I tried to use `float:left` but it didn't work.

```css
.list ul  
{
    
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    
}
```

```html
  <div class="list">
            <h1>Practices</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>Antitrust</li>
                <li>Appellate</li>
                <li>Copyright</li>
                <li>International Patent</li>
                <li>International Disputes</li>
                <li>Litigation & Arbitration</li>
            </ul>
            <h1>Industries</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>Agriculture & Energy</li>
                <li>Computer & Technology</li>
                <li>Environmental</li>
                <li>Life Sciences</li>
                <li>Medical Device</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap the `<h1>` and the `<ul>` to a `<div>` and set the `float:left;` property to this element.

Then set the `.list` element to have the `vertical-align:top;` property.

```css
.list
{  
    vertical-align:top;
}

.list ul  
{
    list-style:none;
}

.list .ul-wrapper  
{
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
    <div class="ul-wrapper">
        <h1>Practices</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Antitrust</li>
            <li>Appellate</li>
            <li>Copyright</li>
            <li>International Patent</li>
            <li>International Disputes</li>
            <li>Litigation & Arbitration</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="ul-wrapper">
        <h1>Industries</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Agriculture & Energy</li>
            <li>Computer & Technology</li>
            <li>Environmental</li>
            <li>Life Sciences</li>
            <li>Medical Device</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This probably will occur if the element that contains them has not enough width to fit both `.ul-wrapper` elements alongside. Take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3rq8d616/), setting the `.list` to have `width:200px;` makes the second `.ul-wrapper` to go under the first.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go sir:

```
<style>
    .ul-wrapper{float:left;}
</style>    
<div class="list">
    <div class="ul-wrapper">
        <h1>Practices</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Antitrust</li>
            <li>Appellate</li>
            <li>Copyright</li>
            <li>International Patent</li>
            <li>International Disputes</li>
            <li>Litigation & Arbitration</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="ul-wrapper">
        <h1>Industries</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Agriculture & Energy</li>
            <li>Computer & Technology</li>
            <li>Environmental</li>
            <li>Life Sciences</li>
            <li>Medical Device</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```